# Фильтрация вложенного списка, функциональное программирование

Tags: python, list

Как мне отфильтровать вложенный лист list_even_odd, так чтобы для входного списка списков получить список нечётных по порядку списков (первый, третий и так далее), оставив в каждом только нечётные по порядку элементы. Например, для из списка [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] должен получиться список [[1, 3], [7, 9]].

```
list_even_odd = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ['c', 'a', 't'],
    ['d', 'o', 'g'],
    [100, 200, 300, 400],
    [True, False],
    [],
    [],
]


# не подходит надо по индексу а не по значению иначе пропускает [] 
list_even = filter(lambda index: list_even_odd.index(index) % 2 == 0, list_even_odd.copy())
list_filter_even = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda item: x.index(item) % 2 == 0, x)), list_even))
```

Comment: `[sl[::2] for sl in list_even_odd[::2]]` так? Не очень понятно, как вы ожидаете получить указанный в вопросе результат.

Comment: Например, для из списка [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] должен получиться список [[1, 3], [7, 9]].

Comment: Значит, используйте списковое включение из 1 комментария.

Comment: Благодарю за мысль, а как сделать фильтрацию через анонимную функцию? lambda как тут [sl[::2] for sl in list_even_odd[::2]] ?

Comment: А зачем? Рекурсивно красиво обойти не получится, надо будет явно прописывать два фильтра. Ну или пока в голову не приходит лучшее решение.

Comment: я вот что хотел map(lambda sl: sl[::2], list_even_odd[::2])

Comment: @Mrhagal Ну вот и напишите своё решение как ответ.

Comment: @CrazyElf
а как еще вот это выражение [sl[::2] for sl in list_even_odd[::2]]
записать простым циклом for чтобы перезаписать текущий лист?
    for item in list_even_odd[::2]:
       item[::2] = ?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с `for`

```py
leo = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] #входные данные
lod = [i[::2] for i in leo[::2]] #берём только нечётные вложенные списки, а в них оставляем только нечётные списки
print(lod)
```

Тоже самое с `map`(применяет функцию ко всем элементам списка, **возвращает итерируемый объект, не список**, по этому **тип надо сменить на список**, как сделал я) и анонимной функцией, о которой говорил автор в комментариях

```py
leo = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] #входные данные
lod = list(map(lambda lt: lt[::2], leo[::2])) #берём только нечётные вложенные списки и применяем к ним функцию которая оставляет только нечётные элементы, после этого приводим тип объекта к list
print(lod)
```

Комбо – `for` и `lambda` (**не рекомендуется использовать**, однако упомянуть думаю будет не лишним):

```py
leo = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] #входные данные
f = lambda lt: lt[::2]
lod = [f(i) for i in leo[::2]] #проходимся по нечётным вложенным спискам, применяя к ним функцию, которая оставлять только нечётные элементы
print(lod)
```

Comment: Благодарю, а как написать простой  цикл for аналог этому [i[::2] for i in leo[::2]] 
начал не пойму как перезаписать значения листа for item in list_even_odd[::2]:
     list_even_odd[::2][item] = item[::2] ???

Comment: `lamba -> lambda`. И с последним примером что-то явно не так.

Comment: Опечатался, простите) Бывает такое

Comment: всё, готово) Ошибки нет. Заработался и не выспался)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, подскажи еще как изменить список-аргумент по месту, а не возвращать его новую версию list, после фильтрации?